# How to prevent committing of an empty Avro file into HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, avro

I have a job that create a Avro file into HDFS and append the file with data. However, occasionally there wont be any data for appending, in that case I don't want the application to flush and close the file, instead it should check whether the file is empty or not (but I assume thatthe Avro schema will be written into the header so technically not an empty file) and delete the file if it is empty.

Is this feasible with Avro+HDFS lib?

Answer (score 4):

Try using [LazyOutputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/LazyOutputFormat.html) when specifying the output format for your job. It creates output lazily, meaning that an output file will only be created if output exists.

So instead of writing something like:
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

You can use LazyOutputFormat like this instead:
    LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);

Comment: Does this work correctly with avro or should the TextOutputFormat.class be AvroOutputFormat.class

Comment: This is a very detailed and well thought out answer but don't you think it's a bit lazy to use lazyoutput format when you could build something on your own.