# Configure Sqoop for LazyOutpuFormat

Tags: sqoop, avro

I'm have the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408517/how-to-prevent-committing-of-an-empty-avro-file-into-hdfs)

Sqoop is generating empty avro files (with schema only) in HDFS. I want to use LazyOutputFormat to fix this but how can I configure sqoop to use LazyOutputFormat?